# Anyone familiar with Vimeo? Trouble with js_onLoad, broken?

Tags: vimeo

Hi all I was trying to get the vimeo "swfobject.html" example from git hub to work, but it simply doesn't work @ github.com/vimeo/vimeo-api-examples/blob/master/moogaloop-api/javascript/swfobject.html

I debugged a bit, and realized it doesn't even enter the "js_onLoad" function. Does anyone know if this github code dated or is js_onLoad deprecated? I'm just trying to do a simple example of displaying the alert "hi" after the player is loaded, but I can't even get that far.

My very simple sample code is here: http://pastie.org/1110855. Does anyone see a problem?

Any fellow stackoverflowers versed in vimeo JS API? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain.  There's a bunch of inconsistent information about the vimeo API out there.  But there are still parts that work.  Check out the [API Playground](http://player.vimeo.com/playground) which works and demonstrates clearly how to do all sorts of useful things.  The source code is [on github](https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript).  You can take apart the playground.html file and just leave in the parts that you need.

Important caveat about the playground.html file -- it doesn't work (for me) when running off a file:/// URL.  It has to be coming off an http server to function at all.  HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Leopd. The playground page works well for me on Chrome (where it's embedded in HTML5), but not on Firefox (where it's embedded in Flash)... Looks like Universal Embed is not *that* universal in the end!

Answer (score 0):

I consider myself a bit of an expert on the Vimeo JS API. Their documentation and demo's are very poor, so I put together this little demo that I think it much easier to follow. It users jQuery and the iFrame embed method, but hopefully it helps:
http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/vimeo/froogaloop2-api-basics.html

It shows how to listen for an event and fire a method.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Drew. This link works well for me on Chrome (where it's embedded in HTML5), but not on Firefox (where it's embedded in Flash)...

Answer (score 0):

After several experiments, it seems that events are only fired with the HTML5 version of the embed, not with the Flash version.

As the Universal Embed code (iframe) automatically selects the technology, I believe that the best way to go is to avoid using it and make your own embed.